# Graql creation schema grakn.core.kb.concept.api.EntityType Issue

Tags: database, graph, database-design, schema, vaticle-typeql

im new in graph db, I have an error in my grql code and I don't know the reason.

The error that grql givme is:

UNKNOWN: The concept [Base Type [Role] - Id - is not of type [interface grakn.core.kb.concept.api.EntityType]

```
define

ruc sub attribute,
    datatype string;

about sub attribute,
    datatype string;

web-page sub attribute,
    datatype string;

location sub attribute,
    datatype string;

name sub attribute,
    datatype string;

creationDate sub attribute,
    datatype date;

dni sub attribute,
    datatype string;

championshipWon sub attribute,
    datatype long;

birdhdate sub attribute,
    datatype date;

yearsExperience sub attribute,
    datatype long;

duration sub attribute,
    datatype long;

sessionDate sub attribute,
    datatype date;

cost sub attribute,
    datatype long;

maxStudents sub attribute,
    datatype long;

minStudents sub attribute,
    datatype long;

maxTickets sub attribute,
    datatype long;

email sub attribute,
    datatype string;

password sub attribute,
    datatype string;

disciplines sub attribute,
    datatype string;

title sub attribute,
    datatype string;

schedule sub attribute,
    datatype string;

credentials sub entity,
    has email,
    has password;

school sub entity,
    relates students,
    relates trainers,
    relates credentials,
    plays creator,
    has ruc,
    has about,
    has location,
    has name,
    has creationDate,
    has disciplines;

trainers sub entity,
    relates students,
    plays creator,
    has dni,
    has championshipWon,
    has name,
    has birdhdate,
    has creationDate,
    has disciplines,
    has yearsExperience;


personalSession sub entity,
    relates students,
    relates trainers,
    plays creating,
    has sessionDate,
    has duration,
    has cost,
    has location,
    has disciplines;

schoolSession sub entity,
    relates school,
    relates trainers,
    relates students,
    plays creating,
    has cost,
    has duration,
    has schedule,
    has maxStudents,
    has minStudents,
    has location;

events sub entity,
    relates school,
    relates trainers,
    plays creating,
    has cost,
    has maxTickets,
    has title,
    has sessionDate,
    has location;

students sub entity,
    has dni,
    has name,
    has birdhdate,
    has creationDate,
    has disciplines;

create sub relation,
    relates creator,
    relates creating;
```

As you can see I think all the things are correct, but they givme that error, please help!

Answer (score 0):

`relates` is meant to be used within the definition of a `relation`, however, you're using it within `entity` definitions. You can learn more about the construction of [Schema Concepts in the Grakn Documentation](http://dev.grakn.ai/docs/schema/concepts).